# SQL Server xml modify insert method condtional insert

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, insert, conditional-statements

I have this xml and I want to insert a `<TICKED>` node and a `<DISABLED>` node for the `/COUNTRY/DisplayValue` specified in a variable, but only if a `<TICKED>` node doesn't already exist.

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML;

SET @xml = '
      <COUNTRY TICKOPTION="Y">
        <DisplayValue>IRELAND</DisplayValue>
        <ReportValue>[Hierarchy].[CIMSHierarchy].[Country Name].&amp;[IRELAND]</ReportValue>
        <TICKED>Y</TICKED>
      </COUNTRY>
      <COUNTRY TICKOPTION="Y">
        <DisplayValue>CANADA</DisplayValue>
        <ReportValue>[Hierarchy].[CIMSHierarchy].[Country Name].&amp;[CANADA]</ReportValue>
        <TICKED>Y</TICKED> 
      </COUNTRY>      
      <COUNTRY TICKOPTION="Y">
        <DisplayValue>INDIA</DisplayValue>
        <ReportValue>[Hierarchy].[CIMSHierarchy].[Country Name].&amp;[INDIA]</ReportValue>
        <TICKED>Y</TICKED> 
      </COUNTRY>'

DECLARE @HC_Country_DV AS VARCHAR(255);

SET @HC_Country_DV = 'CANADA'

SET @xml.modify('
insert (<TICKED>Y</TICKED>,<DISABLED>Y</DISABLED>) 
into (/COUNTRY[DisplayValue = sql:variable("@HC_Country_DV")])[1]')

SELECT @xml
```

When I do this, I get two entries for `<TICKED>`

```
<COUNTRY TICKOPTION="Y">
  <DisplayValue>IRELAND</DisplayValue>
  <ReportValue>[Hierarchy].[CIMSHierarchy].[Country Name].&amp;[IRELAND]</ReportValue>
  <TICKED>Y</TICKED>
</COUNTRY>
<COUNTRY TICKOPTION="Y">
  <DisplayValue>CANADA</DisplayValue>
  <ReportValue>[Hierarchy].[CIMSHierarchy].[Country Name].&amp;[CANADA]</ReportValue>
  <TICKED>Y</TICKED>
  <TICKED>Y</TICKED>
  <DISABLED>Y</DISABLED>
</COUNTRY>
<COUNTRY TICKOPTION="Y">
  <DisplayValue>INDIA</DisplayValue>
  <ReportValue>[Hierarchy].[CIMSHierarchy].[Country Name].&amp;[INDIA]</ReportValue>
  <TICKED>Y</TICKED>
</COUNTRY>
```

I can't quite figure out how to only insert the `<TICKED>` node once, I played with the "if" condition in modify but couldn't figure it out. I considered the "delete" modify method to remove one but I though I'd ask here and see if you guys can help me out again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but only if a `<TICKED>` node doesn't already exist.

Add a check for a `TICKED` node. `and not(TICKED)`.

```
SET @xml.modify('
insert (<TICKED>Y</TICKED>,<DISABLED>Y</DISABLED>) 
into (/COUNTRY[DisplayValue = sql:variable("@HC_Country_DV") and not(TICKED)])[1]')
```

Comment: Thanks again Mikael that does it, as you can probably tell I'm new to XML and not very good!